# Is there a different way integer promotion will be handle in "uint8_t | (uint8_t << 8)"?

Tags: c++, c, integer

In the following program, it seems that a[1] is shifted by eight bit and goes to 0 and the print value should be 1. But integer promotion actually happens and the print value of b is 257. I am running gcc version 4.8.2 on x86-64.

Here is the question: will integer promotion be handled in a different way so the print value is not 257 without changing the code by changing processor and compilers (processor options limited to x86, x86-64, and all ARM)?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<inttypes.h>

int main(){
  uint8_t *a;
  a = (uint8_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*2);
  uint16_t b;
  a[0] = 1; a[1] = 1;
  b = a[0] | (a[1] << 8);
  printf("b = %d\n", b);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This promotion is not a bug. You cannot "fix" it by changing processors or compilers.

Comment: If you want to continue the computation with truncated intermediate values, you need to force it: `a[0] | (uint8_t)(a[1] << 8)` Although I don't see the point in doing that...

Comment: Without integer promotion,how a[1] << 8 can be computed? Left shift 8 bit is not possible with 8-bit data (I mean this will zeroed then), so integer promotion has to be there and will be

Comment: @DebasishJana If this would be the reason, to what will it be promoted if I write `a[1] << 10000`?

Comment: @user2357112, my previous title is not accurate. I mean is there any other way the integer promotion will be handle. could you elaborate on the "fix"?

Comment: a[1] << 10000 will cause an overflow

Comment: @leemes, I mean without changing the code.

Comment: @DebasishJana, <<10000 will result in print value 1 (on my setup only). But this is not my question. My question is about different integer promotion behavior without changing the code.

Comment: No, it will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ok then I ask the same thing with `a[1] << 48`. It could fit in a `long long` but it isn't promoted to such (AFAIK). But @DebasishJana wrote it like that (i.e. that it is promoted *in order to fit* the shifted bits).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> will integer promotion be handled in a different way so the print value is not 257?

No.  The integer promotions always take place, meaning both `a[0]` and `a[1]` are promoted to `int` before the shift or the bitwise OR take place.

From the spec:

> If an **`int`** can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an **`int`**...